# JNA: Use one thread for all callbacks

Tags: java, jna

I have a situation where I am using JNA with some native code with callbacks and I am noticing that for each callback the main thread of the native code makes it makes a new java thread to handle the callback. Is there a way with JNA to specify which thread deals with callbacks so I can get them all on the same thread? As it currently is I am getting thousands of new threads every few seconds and it is quite a resource drain.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of digging I found the proper answer. I created a CallbackThreadInitilizer and used the Native.addCallbackThreadInitilizer method to associate it with each callback. That put them all on the same thread. If you have a finished callback or have some sort of flag you send to indicate that this callback is the last you can call Native.detatch(true) in that case to detach the thread and let it be cleaned up by the gc. If you do not it seems to hang around for a while and sometimes make new ones and close the old. I never saw it keep more than 3 at once.